# Save string format specifiers (%@, %d, etc.) in NSString for future placeholder use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a long string I want to retrieve from a URL and store at app launch. Later, I want to insert individual values into that string.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
NSString *numberLine = @"1 %@ 3 %@ 5 %@";

//... (later) ...

NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:numberLine, @"two", @"four", @"six"]; 

NSLog(@"%@", final); //Should output "1 two 3 four 5 six"
```

I want the `@"two"` to be inserted into the placeholder `%@` that was earlier saved into `numberLine`.

Is there a good way to accomplish something like this?

So far my only thought is to do something like:

```
NSString *script = @"width = PLACEHOLDERpx";
script = [script stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PLACEHOLDER" withString:@"12"];
```

Comment: It's not clear -- your first scheme works just fine.  What do you want to accomplish beyond that?

Comment: Arg, you're right. I could have sworn my original problem wasn't working, although that was a much larger string of text. Maybe I had another error in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is a template. You want to leave placeholders in a string that will be filled out with data. While you could use %@ and %d through a string that gets difficult as the string grows more complex. You may want to use a template library like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) for [Objective-C](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache). This will let you write expressions like this:

```
Hello {{SomeVariable}}
```

All you have to do is pass in an `NSDictionary` with keys that correspond to the data you want to render. So for the example above you might do the following:

```
NSString *result = [GRMustacheTemplate renderObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"World" forKey:@"SomeVariable"];
                                         fromString:@"Hello {{SomeVariable}}"
                                              error:NULL];
```

This will produce a `result` string `Hello World`.